# Send array of numbers from JS to asp.net MVC action

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, http-post

I want to send array of numbers to my back action and I am getting NULL or error whatever I try. This is my current code.

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
        traditional: true,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(groupIds),
        url: '/Admin/ReadMessages',
        error: function (error) {
            swal.fire({
                title: "Something went wrong. Please try again later.",
                type: "error"
            });
        }
    });
```

**MVC**

```
public ActionResult ReadMessages(List<long> groupIds)
{
     return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clear out for others, as @Amin stated and I realized, error was in sending NON array object, I was using map function and it returned some jquery array, but when I instantiated `new Array` and sent it, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
var arr= new Array();
arr.push(1);
arr.push(2); 

$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",
    url: urlToPost,
    data: JSON.stringify(arr),
    contentType: "application/json"
   });
```

Comment: U helped me realize what I was doing wrong, error isn't in post it's in my array... Ty

Comment: @Serlok exactly I thought about it  so I decided to put  the array here. so i'm happy to help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    traditional: true,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type: "POST",
    data: { 'groupIds': groupIds} ,
    url: '/Admin/ReadMessages',
    error: function (error) {
        swal.fire({
            title: "Something went wrong. Please try again later.",
            type: "error"
        });
    }
});
```

And in Controller  :

```
public ActionResult ReadMessages(IEnumerable<long> groupIds))
{
     return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    traditional: true,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type: "POST",
    data:{groupIds:groupIds},
    url:'@Url.Action("ReadMessages", "Admin")',
    error: function (error) {
        swal.fire({
            title: "Something went wrong. Please try again later.",
            type: "error"
        });
    }
});
```

controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ReadMessages(IEnumerable<long> groupIds))
{
     return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```